# Cython issue installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

I am trying to run sklearn, which I can import in Python 2.7.11, but 
there was an installation problem. I tried going to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn and ran

```
python setup.py install
```

and got into some apparently Cython related issues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 88, in <module>
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
  File "setup.py", line 82, in configuration
    maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/_build_utils/__init__.py", line 84, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
    config.ext_modules = cythonize(config.ext_modules)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 908, in cythonize
    aliases=aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 778, in create_extension_list
    for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 124, in nonempty
    raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: '_check_build.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what the issue might be?

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you install it with pip or conda?

Comment: Same issue installing with Conda

Comment: Ok, please ignore previous ignore issues. The issue was to do with the import command. import sklearn does not make sklearn.linear_model directly available, but doing from sklearn import * makes everything load properly so problem solved.

Comment: Actually it's usually not a good idea to import * (it may import LOTS of stuff, and silently override variables of previsouly imported packages), you should rather import the few functions/classes that you need, or import submodules, or call them explicitly, eg as sklearn.linear_model.LassoClassifier